# Von Mangoldt function implications

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

$$\psi (x)=x-\sum _{\zeta (\rho )=0}{\frac {x^{\rho }}{\rho }}-\log(2\pi ).$$

is the explicit formula for the summatory Mangoldt function. Does this mean  $x$ is alway bigger than $\psi(x)$ ?

Comment: No, $\psi (19)=19.2657$. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Distribution_of_prime_numbers.

Comment: Note that $\rho$ denotes complex numbers, so $x^\rho/\rho$ is not automatically positive. Indeed, that sum is positive asymptotically half the time (in a suitable sense). Note also that you've omitted a term $-\frac12\log(1-x^{-2})$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_for_L-functions#Riemann's_explicit_formula)), although that's not directly relevant to your question.

Comment: very clear... Thank you !

Comment: @GregMartin This is tangential to the post, but I wonder: is it true that that $\psi(x) - x$ is positive half the time? There are various forms of "Chebyshev bias" results that I'm only aware of in passing.

Comment: It has been proved, assuming GRH plus the linear independence of the imaginary parts of the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$, that $(\psi(x)-x)/\sqrt x$ has a continuous limiting logarithmic distribution that is symmetric around $0$, which in particular implies that $\psi(x)-x$ is positive asymptotically half the time on the logarithmic scale. Indeed, the bias towards negative numbers of $\pi(x)-\mathop{\rm li}(x)$ isn't because of that sum, which is present in essentially the same form (!), but rather due to a constant $-1$ arising from discarding the squares of the primes.

Comment: Beware that $\rho$ takes in complex values, so the minus sign in front of the sum over zeros of $\zeta(s)$ may take in negative values.